# Google Analytics custom dimension vs new users

Tags: google-analytics

We have multiple e-learning modules under one domain.

We want to know how many **new users start** each module over a set period of time e.g.

trainingDomain.com/module01 > 4 new starts

trainingDomain.com/module02 > 2 new starts

trainingDomain.com/module03 > 5 new starts

The metric that seems to best fit new starts is new users by module.

We have tried various approaches but no success so far. I suspect we are misunderstanding something conceptual.

Each page in a module saves a moduleID to a custom dimension i.e. click scope. If we create a custom report with new users as the metric and moduleID as the primary dimension, only the first module visited registers in the report.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a better way we can approach this or a way to tweak the current approach to work? I'm really struggling to get my tiny brain around this...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, custom dimension is redundantly for your purpose. 
Create a [page content group](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) with your modules. Then create a custom report with the new users as metric, page as a dimension and filter by your content group.